# github: Find hash (tag) of a specific commit in a download (as .zip or .tar.gz)?

Tags: git, github, hash, commit, zip

Scenario: I have two directories originating from one and the same github repository, but downloaded as .zip (or maybe .tar.gz) at different times.

Question: How can I find the commit hash inside these two directories? Is it even stored anywhere?

Background: I was hacking on some code, got sidetracked, and I have forgotten why I have two different directories. The directories are clearly different (used diff -r dir1 dir2), and the differences are not just MY little hacks. The directories have a file setup.cfg that both contain the line version = 0.3.5, so dirs are the same version/"release" but not the same commit hash. I would like to find out what the commit hashes are/were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has been downloaded as a zip or tar archive, it's not a commit and the hash ID may well be gone.  I believe GitHub stick the raw hash ID into an extended header, as they use `git archive` to do it:

> In the [case where a commit hash ID is used to build the archive] ... Additionally the commit ID is stored in a global extended pax header if the tar format is used; it can be extracted using git get-tar-commit-id. In ZIP files it is stored as a file comment.

You will need the original tar or zip file to test for this.  If it's uncompressed:

```
git get-tar-commit-id < archive
```

If it's already compressed, decompress it with zcat or gunzip or whatever is appropriate on your system:

```
gunzip < foo.tar.gz | git get-tar-commit-id
```

for example.

#### What if you don't have the original archive, or it has no ID?

In general, there is no unique mapping from an extracted source tree back to a particular commit.  In some sense this doesn't matter: if you can obtain a Git *tree* hash for a source tree, and can find *all* the commits that have that tree hash, then all of those commits are the commits that would produce that archive.  But `git archive` potentially omits, adds, or does substitutions in file contents.

Finding the actual tree hash for some set of files is nontrivial, although I have a program that can do it [here](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/githash.py).  Read through the source to learn the conditions under which it can work.  Once you have that, you can search for commits that have that as their `tree` in their commit object, using `git rev-parse`:

```sh
git rev-list $start_points |
while read $chash; do
    thash=$(git rev-parse $chash^{tree})
    [ $thash = $searchfor ] && echo "tree found in commit $chash"
done
```

for instance (untested and you'll need to fill in a few variables).

Comment: I followed the above and had good results with the specific  commands `zcat file.tar.gz | git get-tar-commit-id` and `unzip -z file.zip` and `githash.py somegithubdir`. Would be great of the specific commands could be made explicit in the answer. Thx.

Comment: I did that for the `git get-tar-commit-id` part, which isn't complicated. The githash Python trick doesn't work well for any of the complicated cases and hence really needs effort on the part of the user. :-)